# CompletableFuture: get object before exception was thrown

Tags: java, completable-future

I wonder whether it is possible to get the object that before exception was thrown. Consider the following code:

```
  Stream.of("String", null, "String2").forEach(
            str -> CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(str::length)
                .thenCompose(integer -> CompletableFuture
                    .supplyAsync(() -> integer * 2))
                .handle((result, thr) -> {
                    if (thr != null) {
                       // how to get access to str?
                    }
                }));
```

Note that this code is merely an example. Actual code is different.
`handle` will give two arguments: exception (if it was thrown, and actual result of previous computation).

**I wonder if an exception if thrown, I can get access to the result of first computation that finished without exception. In this case it would be "String" (for first iteration), null (for second iteration), "String2" (for third iteration).**

I have gone through Java documentation and haven't found a way. If there is no way indeed, how would you rewrite the code to have access to the previous object?

Comment: First, you can't have code after a `return` in the same scope. Second, it's not clear to me what you're trying to do. Why are you using `CompletableFuture` here in the first place? The wok you're doing in them is trivial and using a `CompletableFuture` will in all likelihood just slow your program down. Also, _which_ "s" do you want access to? Where is it coming from? How do you want to use it?

Comment: @Slaw Please see my updated post.

Comment: In your specific case you can simply reference `str` since it's in scope. In general, however, only one of two values is passed from the trigger stage to its dependent stage(s)—the result or error, depending on if the triggering stage completed successfully or exceptionally, respectively.